# Excel Formula to COUNTIFS date falls in particular month AND second criteria is "x"

Tags: excel

I have excel data in following format.

```
 Date   In Stock
2/02/16     x
5/02/16     
18/02/16    x
22/02/16    x
14/03/16    
16/03/16    
21/03/16    x
28/03/16    x
1/04/16     
7/04/16     
9/04/16     
8/04/16     x
```

I want to apply a formula for reporting purposes in column E. For each month, tally the total number of 'x'.

```
{COL D}     {COL E}                             {COL F}
Month       Number of Products In Stock         Expected Result
Feb-16                                          3
Mar-16                                          2
Apr-16                                          1
```

Example: For February 2016, I am expecting to see a value of '3' in cell E4.

The formula I have created below doesn't work. The first criteria is using the month function and I am looking for '2' (being February) as the value. The second criteria looks at Column B and the value 'x'.

```
=COUNTIFS(month(A4:A19),2,B4:B19,"x")
```

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data in cols **A** and **B**, try *SUMPRODUCT()*:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A2:A13)=2)*(B2:B13="x"))
```

For *February*:

[image]

You would use ***3*** for *March*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Quite possible with COUNTIFS but the syntax must be observed:

```
=COUNTIFS(A4:A19,">="&F2,A4:A19,"<"&F3,B4:B19,"x")
```

For convenience F1:F12 being loaded with `Jan 16`, `Feb 16` etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUM(IF((MONTH($A$2:$A$13)=MONTH(D2))*(DAY($A$2:$A$13)=DAY(D2))*($B$2:$B$13="x"),1,0))
```

type `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`

[image]